# windows DLL Is there are possibility to use same socket number among multiple threads or processes?

Tags: c++

I have created application(DLL) that updated ikon on windows explorer. I am using tcp socket to communicate with the server(on the same computer)
 where I get status of the file. I have performance issue on directory with many files(names of the file I am getting from the explorer ).
I found bottleneck and is client tcp/ip, where I initialize tcp socket. For example if I have 50 files on directory I am getting 50 threads or processes and each thread or process Initialize Winsock and after that sends data to the server.

This is DLL main where I register server
    STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
    // Register the component.
    hr = RegisterInprocServer(szModule, CLSID_IconOverlay,
        L"LoqOverlayBlue.CustomIcon Class",
        L"Apartment");

And my CustomIcon class with IsMemberOf function where I am getting file name and function GetStatus where I process file by sending to the server to get status of the file 
    // Get the status of the file.
    HRESULT CustomIcon::IsMemberOf(PCWSTR pwszPath, DWORD dwAttrib) {

```
std::string fileName;
HRESULT result = S_FALSE;

std::size_t found = fileName.find("my directory");

if (found != std::string::npos) {
    fileName.append("2;");
        fileName.append(CT2A(pwszPath));
    if (GetStatus(fileName) == Red) {
        return S_OK;
    }       
}

return S_FALSE;
}
```

Function IsMemberOf() called every time I click on refresh button on windows explorer or click on directory and I getting all files inside that directory.
Inside GetStatus function I initialize winsock and send file name to the server to get status of the file in order to update icon on the windows explorer.

Problem I don't know if it thread or process. Is anyone knows if it thread or process?
Is there are any possibility to use same socket number among multiple threads or processes in this particular case?

Comment: Actually I don't know if it thread or process. I was notified by windows explorer if I click refresh directory or just click on directory to see files.

Answer (score 1):

You can share the same socket handle across threads.
There is a specific reason to have one thread for each file?

Instead of share a socket number across threads, maybe is better to create a queue associated with a single communication thread that has the responsibility of the socket. In this way you send each filename to the queue in an unblocking way, and let the socket-thread communicate with the server. If you need the icon resource back, you can let the thread wait for a signal from the socket-server that notify for the resource to be ready.

UPDATE

If you follow this design, is useless to have so many threads waiting for a single thread. You can use another queue updated from the socket-thread to store  the icons arrived, a single thread that scan filenames and another thread to update the icon from the second queue. Following this schema, only 3 threads are needed (or maybe 4 if you separate the socket thread in a writing-thread and a reading-thread).